# Change the csv input by a variable

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to use multiple "Sequences sunburst" from D3. I need to create the informations that are now in a .csv from a php ( in fact Twig , I'm on Symfony 2 ).

The javascript is :

```
// Use d3.text and d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
// row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.
d3.text("visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});
```

Can someone tell me how to change this to a variable javascript that I'll be able to generate with my variables?

Thanks & Regards,

Thomas

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're looking for.  What do you mean when you say "a variable javascript"?

Comment: sorry for being late. In fact I'd like to have something like :
    d3.text("visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {
      var csv = '...........'
      var json = '..........'
      createVisualization(json);
    });

But it fails all time...

Comment: or to have something like : 
d3.text(function() {
  text = '............';
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});

Comment: i managed to be ok but really nasty by using a variable and not using the file... so I'll say it's solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved but nasty :

```
d3.text("/visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {

  test="...\n........";

    var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(test);

    var json = buildHierarchy(csv);


    createVisualization(json);
});
```

The file has to exist till we don't use id..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've entirely understood you correctly, but you could use the `data` attribute, or `input type="hidden"` to embed the {{var}} as part of your template, which could then be targeted using the likes of jQuery, or retrieve the data asynchronously as documented here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests